# Complex line integral along a null homotopic curve and the Cauchy Representation Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

In my complex analysis book, they ask to show that: if $C$ be the circle $|z| = 1$, then $\int_C \frac{z}{z^2+9} dz= 0$ right after the theorem that says that a complex line integral along a piece wise null-homotopic $C^1$ loop is zero.

My guess is that this is the case because $C$ is parametrized by $[-\pi,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: t \mapsto e^{it}$, and since we can continuously deform a circle to a point, this map is null-homotopic.

So then, why is the Cauchy representation formula, i.e. $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial B} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$, where $B$ is an open ball, not always equal to zero? Because then, following the same reason as before, the border of an open ball can be continuously deformed to a point.

Could anyone point out the flaw in my intuition?

Comment: Do you have poles inside the contour?

Comment: If the integrand does not have poles inside the contour, what do you expect the answer is? Check Cauchy theorem?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, so far the course has not said anything about poles :). Is my assumption about the first integral wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

The theorem about "complex line integral along a piece wise null-homotopic C1 loop is zero" requires that the function you are integrating is holomorphic on the set your homotopy is passing through. In practice, this means that the function should be holomorphic on (a neighbourhood of the closure of) the domain bounded by your loop.

In your particular case, the function $f(z) = \dfrac{z}{z^2+9}$ is holomorphic on the whole complex plane except the points $z = \pm 3i$, so there is no problem. If you try to integrate over a curve containing one or both of $\pm 3i$, $f$ is no longer holomorphic inside the loop and your theorem doesn't apply. In that case, Cauchy's integral formula, or more generally  the Residue theorem, comes into play.

Comment: But, then why isn't the integral in the Cauchy representation formula 0?

Comment: Because $\dfrac{f(w)}{w-z}$ is (generally) not holomorphic at $w=z$.

Comment: But the function $\frac{z}{z^2+9}$ is not holomorphic at $3i$, but since the loop is not passing through this point this is no problem?